# How can I have custom images in GridView Pagination

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.net for coding.

I am having GridView Control in my application.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="innerGridTable" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="TrainerID"
    DataSourceID="TrainerSearchDataSource">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="Button" CommandName="SelectTrainer"
            HeaderText="Select" ShowHeader="True" Text="Select">
            <ControlStyle CssClass="Button" />
        </asp:ButtonField>
        <asp:TemplateField Visible="false" HeaderText="Trainer ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTrainerID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TrainerID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                           
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TrainerName" HeaderText="Trainer Name" ReadOnly="True"
            SortExpression="TrainerName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone number" SortExpression="Phone" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" Visible="false" HeaderText="Email Address" SortExpression="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address1" Visible="false" HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PostCode" HeaderText="PostCode" SortExpression="PostCode" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="Button" CommandName="Archive"
            HeaderText="Archive" ShowHeader="True" Text="Delete">
            <ControlStyle CssClass="Button" />
        </asp:ButtonField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want my custom images in GridView Pagination for "Previous", "Next" etc.

Please suggest what are the option to achieve this functionality.

Thanks.

Best Regards,
Yuv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using below code.

I added  in GridView

```
 <PagerStyle BackColor="LightBlue" CssClass="paginationBlk"  Height="30px" VerticalAlign="Bottom" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <PagerTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" OnCommand="Paginate" CommandArgument="First" CommandName="Page" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/arrow-start-active.gif" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" OnCommand="Paginate" CommandArgument="Prev" CommandName="Page" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/arrow-left-active.gif" />
                            Page
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPages" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPages_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            of
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPageCount" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" OnCommand="Paginate" CommandArgument="Next" CommandName="Page" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/arrow-right-active.gif" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" OnCommand="Paginate" CommandArgument="Last" CommandName="Page" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/arrow-end-active.gif" />
                        </PagerTemplate>
```

and my CS file I added below code:

```
   Protected Sub GridView1_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.DataBound
        Dim gvrPager As GridViewRow
        gvrPager = GridView1.BottomPagerRow

        If gvrPager Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim ddlPages As DropDownList = CType(gvrPager.Cells(0).FindControl("ddlPages"), DropDownList)
        Dim lblPageCount As Label = CType(gvrPager.Cells(0).FindControl("lblPageCount"), Label)

        If ddlPages IsNot Nothing Then
            ' populate pager
            For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.PageCount - 1

                Dim intPageNumber As Integer = i + 1
                Dim lstItem As New ListItem(intPageNumber.ToString())

                If i = GridView1.PageIndex Then
                    lstItem.Selected = True
                End If
                ddlPages.Items.Add(lstItem)
            Next
        End If
        'populate page count
        If lblPageCount IsNot Nothing Then
            lblPageCount.Text = GridView1.PageCount.ToString()
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Paginate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs)
        ' get the current page selected
        Dim intCurIndex As Integer = GridView1.PageIndex

        Select Case e.CommandArgument.ToString().ToLower()
            Case "first"
                GridView1.PageIndex = 0
                Exit Select
            Case "prev"
                GridView1.PageIndex = intCurIndex
                Exit Select
            Case "next"
                GridView1.PageIndex = intCurIndex
                Exit Select
            Case "last"
                GridView1.PageIndex = GridView1.PageCount
                Exit Select
        End Select

        ' popultate the gridview control
        'PopulateGrid()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub ddlPages_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As [Object], ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim gvrPager As GridViewRow = GridView1.BottomPagerRow
        Dim ddlPages As DropDownList = CType(gvrPager.Cells(0).FindControl("ddlPages"), DropDownList)

        GridView1.PageIndex = ddlPages.SelectedIndex

        ' a method to populate your grid
        'PopulateGrid()
    End Sub
```

Please have a look and let me know your feedbacks.

Cheers!

Yuv

Comment: Hi Guys using above code, I am little stuck in maintaining GridView PageIndex. I mean, I want to maintain my GridView PageIndex in Session so that if any record is amended and further when user come back to screen it will be shown same page records from which he has opened the record. Please suggest waiting  for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

GridView has a property named [PagerSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagersettings.aspx).
Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No I wan to add First, Last, Prev, Next button Images as well as pager settings. Can you please give some example code